# Cast LPHMIXER to HMIXER in Windows mmeapi

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to figure out how to call the [`mixerOpen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-mixeropen) and [`mixerClose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-mixerclose) functions using C++ on the Windows 10 platform. I'm using `cl.exe` as the compiler.

The `mixerOpen()` function fills an `LPHMIXER` with a handle to the mixer object. When I call the `mixerClose()` function, it expects a `HMIXER` instead of the `LPHMIXER`.

**Question**: How do I properly cast an `LPHMIXER` to an `HMIXER`, so I can call the `mixerClose()` function?

I tried using `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast`, but they both failed. For example:

```cpp
UINT retval;
LPHMIXER mixer;
retval = mixerOpen(mixer, 0, NULL, 0, MIXER_OBJECTF_AUX);
cout << endl << "Return value: " << retval;

HMIXER hmixer = dynamic_cast<HMIXER>(mixer);
mixerClose(hmixer);
```

... shows the error:

> the operand of a pointer dynamic_cast must be a pointer to a complete class type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPHMIXER` is just a typedef for `HMIXER *`. The sequence to open/use/close the mixer object is:

```
HMIXER hmixer;
MMRESULT retval = mixerOpen(&hmixer, 0, NULL, 0, MIXER_OBJECTF_AUX);
if(retval != MMSYSERR_NOERROR) { /* error */ }

/* use hmixer */

retval = mixerClose(hmixer);
```